# How does it work: smartphone pixels are turned off when heated

Tags: lcd

I saw this video:
https://youtu.be/urbhA37a70c?t=1m45s

In the video you will see that the pixels of a smartphone are turned off when heated. The pixels are turned back on again when they cool down. Does each pixel has a temperature sensor? :o

I wonder how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as the "clearing" temperature of the LC material. Because they are quasi crystals whose behaviour is dictated by inter-molecular forces (typically van der Waals) this is easily disrupted by thermal energy. The hotter it becomes the more the material vibrates and the less likely that the crystalline structures will form. The lower temperature limit is due to viscosity.

Answer (score 1):

This is not surprising. Liquid crystals are notoriously temperature-sensitive. In fact, one of the first uses for them was those flat stick-on temperature indicators in which the numbers changed color as the temperature changed. Remember those?